# Complex number in R

Tags: r

I know that you can easily define a complex number z by doing for instance :
`z <- 3 + 2i`. But when I want to define a function that creates a complex number:

```
f <- function(x,y){
x + yi
}
f(1,2)
```

I get this error message :

> Error in f(1, 2) : object 'yi' not found.

I don't want to use the `complex` function, because in my case, it is really difficult to find the real and imaginary parts of my complex number.

How can I do ?

Comment: May be `as.complex(y)`

Comment: It doesn't work, `Error in f(1, 2) : object 'i' not found`

Comment: @zx8754 No, x + y * 1i.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `i` notation will only work with numbers (because a variable in R can't start with a number). Otherwise it will interpret `yi` as a different variable named "yi" and not convert `y` to a complex number. Instead, use multiplication explicitly with `*`

```
f <- function(x,y){
    x + y * 1i
}
f(1,2)
# [1] 1+2i
```

Answer (score 2):

The `complex()` function is designed for exactly this purpose.

```
f <- function(x,y){
  complex(real = x, imaginary = y)
}

f(1,2)
# [1] 1+2i
```

[Here's](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/complex.html) a handy guide for working with complex numbers in R.